# Which hypothesis test should I use in this scenario?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I have a sample of stroke survivors, I'm trying to determine if there is a difference in age group (<59, 59, 60, >60) as to whether they are employed or not (yes, no).

I'm unsure which hypothesis test I need, I'm considering Kruskal-Wallis, Pearson's Chi-squared, and Chi-squared test for trend. I believe the data fills assumptions for all 3. What do you think?

Thanks in advance,

Warm regards,
Harry

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is there are reason you are pooling everyone younger than $59$ into one group and everyone older than $60$ into another? // How would you employ each of those three tests you mentioned?

Comment: What's the specific alternative you're interested in identifying?

Comment: Are you trying to treat one variable as an independent variable and one as a dependent variable ?  (If so, which is which ?)  Or, instead, looking for an association that doesn't designate a dependent variable ?

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your reply and the welcome, I'm quite new to stats. No, I thought the group divisions were quite strange too, but that’s the data set I’ve been given for the task

// Kruskal-Wallis: I thought to test for difference in variance between the groups based on whether they have a job. // Pearson’s: To test for association between the two variables // Test for trend: I have since realised test for trend probably isn’t suitable

Comment: @Glen_b No unfortunately no specific alternative hypothesis, I just have to do what i can. Presumably Ho: There is no difference between job status between age groups

Comment: @SalMangiafico No I wasn't trying to for sure, I assumed I'd be looking for an association as it isn't an experiment, but I'm very new to stats!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to treat your variable *Age* as an ordinal variable (ordered category).  Since *Employed* is dichotomous, it could be treated as either nominal (nominal category) or ordinal.

Since you aren't interested in treated one variable as a dependent variable per se, you are looking for a test of association and the degree of association.

A common way to do this is with Kendall correlation (particularly Kendall's *tau*-c since the number of categories in each variable are different).  Spearman's correlation will also work reasonably well, as will Kendall's *tau*-b.

Another approach is the Cochran-Armitage test or the linear-by-linear test, which I suspect is the same as what you are calling chi-square test of trend.